# Hydration error in NextJS - No clue what is causing it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So have this simple nextjs site, it's bascially a blog style, with the index page hosting my posts and then an about page.

That's it ... give or take a few components to make things easier...but i have this hydration issue which I can't seem to resolve. I have read it could be about the dates being rendered on the sevrver vs whats in my code.

But really not sure at all, it's driving me nuts.

Here are the main files, if anyone could take a look at point me in the right direction that would be grand. I have used the React dev tools and it seems the hydration is happening on `Root`

```js
// _app.js

import '../styles/globals.css'
import '../styles/one-dark.css'

import Prism from 'prismjs'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'

MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

function MyApp({Component, pageProps}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    Prism.highlightAll()
  })

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

```js
// index.jsx

import Link from 'next/link'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {Suspense, useEffect} from 'react'
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import Moment from 'react-moment'
import Layout from '../layouts/layoutMain'
import {client} from '../utils/contentful-client'

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const posts = await client.getEntries({content_type: 'posts'})

  return {
    props: {
      posts: posts.items,
    },
  }
}

Home.propTypes = {
  posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}

export default function Home({posts}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    getStaticProps()
  }, [])

  return (
    <Layout title="Home">
      {posts.map(post => (
        <div key={post.sys.id} className="">
          <Link
            href={`/posts/${encodeURIComponent(post.fields.slug)}`}
            passHref
          >
            <div>
              <h3 className="link not-prose">{post.fields.title}</h3>
            </div>
          </Link>
          <div className="mb-4">
            <span className="text-sm">Published on </span>
            <Suspense>
              <Moment format="MMM D, YYYY" className="text-sm">
                {post.fields.date}
              </Moment>
            </Suspense>
          </div>

          <div className="trunc-md">
            <ReactMarkdown suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
              {post.fields.content}
            </ReactMarkdown>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

```js
// about.jsx

import React from 'react'
import Tools from '../components/tools'
import Layout from '../layouts/layoutMain'

const social = [
  {
    name: 'Github',
    url: 'https://github.com/xxxx',
  },
  {
    name: 'Linkedin',
    url: 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxx',
  },
  {
    name: 'Email',
    url: 'mailto:xxx@gmail.com',
  },
]

export default function About() {
  return (
    <Layout title="About">
      <section>


        <div>
          <ul className="">
            {social.map(l => (
              <li key={l.name}>
                <a href={l.url} className="link">
                  {l.name}
                </a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section>
        <h2>What applications do you use?</h2>

        <Tools />
      </section>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

```js
// layoutMain.jsx

import Head from 'next/head'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Footer from '../components/footer'
import Header from '../components/header'

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.string,
}

export default function Layout({children, title = ''}) {
  return (
    <div className="flex min-h-screen flex-col">
      <Head>
        <title>{title} &bull; Paul Bennett</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Paul Bennett"></meta>
      </Head>

      <Header />

      <main className="container prose flex-grow font-mono">{children}</main>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I fixed the issue by following here: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/#the-solution

Comment: _"it could be about the dates being rendered on the sevrver vs whats in my code"_ - Yes, that's most likely what the issue is. Try dynamically importing the `Moment` component using [`next/dynamic`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) with `ssr: false`.